# ReactJS and Promise: How to call catch inside then?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, es6-promise, redux-thunk

So, I have got an action creator (that returns a function - I use redux-thunk). Inside the function the creator returns, I call a dispatch method and chain the `then` and `catch` methods. 
Here how it looks like:

```
export function actionCreator(someData) {
    (dispath, getState) => {
        return dispatch(someAction)
        .then(resp => {
            //do something
            // GO TO CATCH
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return err;
        })
    }
}
```

You see the **GO TO CATCH** comment over there? So, how can I go to the catch block from there?

Thank you!

Comment: throw an error? return a Promise.reject(...)? that's two ways

Comment: What is `do something` and why do you need to go to catch? Please, provide more specific code to understand your case.

Comment: though, if that is your actual catch code .. you can just return from the .then whatever you would throw or Promise.reject ... same same result

Comment: Catch exists for error handling. Are you absolutely sure you want to manually visit that block without the presence of an error? Surely there is a better way to achieve your ulterior goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to jump from the body of a `.then()` to the following `.catch()`, the easiest way is to throw an error:

```
throw new Error('I meant to blow up here.');
```

The error you throw is what will be passed to the body of the `.catch()` (the `err` variable, in your case).

Please note that your example already looks suspect though: your catch block is catching an error and then *returning* it as if the error was a regular value, which means any upstream promise-based handling will assume the dispatch was successful. Are you sure that's what you want?